# Travelling outside the US, have an H1B valid for another 2 years, but passport expires in 5.5 half months when I'm back

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports, h1b-visas, french-citizens

I have a French passport with a valid H1B visa stamped and work in the US. The H1B is valid until 2025. I'm flying for work from the US to France on October 1st, and when I fly back my passport will have slightly below 6 months of validity -- 170 days instead of 180 days. It's also tough to get a new passport on time for October 1st. Will I be denied reentry into the US on October 5th?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nonimmigrant is inadmissible under [8 USC 1182(a)(7)(B)(i)(I)](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title8-section1182&num=0&edition=prelim#substructure-location_a_7_B_i_I) unless they have a passport valid until 6 months after the end of their period of admission. What this means in practice is that for people with passports from countries not on the "6-month club", their passport must be valid for at least 6 months at the time of entry, and the admit-until date on their I-94 will be no later than 6 months before their passport expires. For people with passports from countries on the [6-month club](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040309.html#M403_9_3_B_2), their passport must be valid for any length at the time of entry, and the admit-until date on their I-94 will be no later than their passport expiration date.

Since you are using a French passport, and France is in the 6-month club, you can enter the US with a passport of less than 6 months of validity left. However, note that you will be admitted on your I-94 to no later than your passport expiration date. If you wish to stay longer than that, either 1) your employer would have to file another I-129 for H1b extension, or 2) you would have to leave and re-enter the US on a new passport (you would not need to get a new visa on the new passport, since a valid US visa in an expired passport can be used in combination with a valid passport from the same country).

This is as far as the US government is concerned. It is possible that the airline and/or originating country may have stricter requirements for passport validity.

Comment: Thanks, seems the right answer indeed. I’ll simply go up and down to Canada since I live just 4 hours  from the Canadian border. Entry into Canada is visa free (using ETA) for French passport holders.

Comment: @goingaround: If you go to Canada by land, you don't even need eTA

Answer (score 2):

The 6-month rule does not apply to citizens of France. See [this PDF](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2022-Mar/Six-Month%20Passport%20Validity%20Update%2020220316.pdf).

Comment: Whilst this is true, the OP's I-94 expiry date will most likely be linked to the passport expiry data, which could cause all sorts of other issues...

Comment: Thank you leaderboard . @Doc That’s true and that was already the case (I94 end date) since my H1B has a three validity. Canada gives visa free entry to French citizens (on ETA) and so going up and down is quite easy.